# Convolving two grids in matlab and getting shifted output

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, signal-processing, convolution

I would like to convolve two grids in Matlab using the conv2 function. I understand how to do it and the size of resulting output. But I am a bit uncertain, as to how to understand the output.

Say, my image is 
`A = [1 1 1; 1 2 1; 2 3 4]` and the filter is `B = [1 0 0; 0 0 1; 0 1 0]`.

The output for convolution is

```
C = conv2(A, B)

C =

 1     1     1     0     0
 1     2     2     1     1
 2     4     6     3     1
 0     1     4     4     4
 0     2     3     4     0
```

I understand how we get this output and the calculations involved. But my question is - this is the whole output. I can use the `'same'` option with conv2 and get the same sized matrix as the image.

But, is my output not shifted somehow? I read it in several places where they said that the output is shifted down by 1. I do not understand in what way and which direction. Should I start reading the output at 2 (2nd row, 2nd column)?

Can anyone help me by letting me know, where to start reading the output so that I get the same sized output as the image which has been convolved by the filter? Does using `'same'` option give the result I am seeking or do I have to perform further processing of the output to get the convolved image?

I tried zero-padding on all sides - but still can not make sense of the output.

Comment: No it isn't. if you want the strict convolution you have to select `C(1+d:end-d, 1+d:end-d)` with `d = floor(size(B,1)/2)`. it give the same result as using `con2(A,B. 'same')`.

Comment: What do you mean by strict convolution?

Comment: Strict in term of size. Do you understand why the size of the output change?

Comment: I understand, how it changes. That is: if [Xa,Ya] = size(A); [Xb,Yb] = size(B), then Xc = max(Xa+Xb-1,Xa,Xb) and Yc = max(Ya+Yb-1, Ya, Yb).

This is due to cyclically rotating the filter, so that the central element of filter is on the top of the input image element and summing it up. Is that the "why" you asked? 
I can not think of any other reason though.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez, what's up with the modification of the data? You just added a random last row ...

Comment: @R.Bergamote Thanks. No idea how that happened.

Answer (score 0):

Just in order to have simpler numerical values: I set the value of the image and filter as follow:

```
A = [1 1 1; 
     1 1 1; 
     1 1 1]

B = [0 0 0; 
     0 1 0; 
     0 0 0]

C = conv2(A,B)
```

The output is the following one

```
C =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

The ones value are the result of the convolution, the zeros come from the zero padding. The one in the centre is the result of the convolution of all the points from your filter (that is what is returned by `conv2(A,B, 'valid')`).

There is nothing wrong with what is returned by the Matlab answer. If the size of your filter is even, then it is a bit more funny but the proper response from the convolution is the one obtained by valid anyway.